# Django datatime field is autoadding 7 hours

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu

I am copying data from one MySQL table into another in Django.

```
article = Article.objects.get(id=10)
article2 = ArchivedArticles(title=article.title, content= article.content, publishdate = article.publishdate)
article2.save()
```

However the publish date in ArchivedArticles table is changed to 7Hours+ 
for example if the publish date in Articles table is '2016-08-23 17:58:00' in ArticleArchived table it is '2016-08-24 00:58:00'

publishdate for both tables is defined in the Models as

```
publishdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column='PublishDate', blank=True, editable=False, verbose_name="Date")
```

and in MYSQL it is as below for both tables

```
publishdate TIMESTAMP NOTNULL Default = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Is the timezone correct in settings.py?

Comment: Remember MYSQL saves datetime columns in UTC otherwise timezone shifting would be a nightmare. Is this the issue. What do you see when you read the data back using your app

Comment: Yes. In settings.py it is specified as TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

Comment: I see the correct date time when I read it back. Must be some issue in saving. I wonder how assignment works in creating the ArticleArchive object. i.e. publishdate = article.publishdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the field type to "DateTime" from "TimeStamp" in both tables and it is fixed.